# Convergence of a sequence of roots

Tags: sequences-and-series, functions

Consider the equation
$$
\frac{\ln\left(x\right)}{x}=\frac{1}{n}
$$

I've shown that on $\left[1,e\right]$, there's a unique solution $a_n$. The sequence $\left(a_n\right)$ decreases and $a_n \geq 1$ so the sequence converges. I know that the limit of $a_n$ is $1$, how can I show it ? Any hint ?

Edit :
Am I allowed to right that it implies
$Ln(l)/l=0$ ?

Comment: Given $\varepsilon >0$ you need to find some $a_N$ with $1<a_N<1+\varepsilon$.

Comment: You can get $a_n=-nW_0(-\frac1n)$ with the Lambert-W function. Now you would need to show that $W_0$ is differentiable in $0$, then the limit is $W_0'(0)$.